# How to estimate the height of UITableViewCell according to the height of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm developing the chat application.

I want to add image posting function.

The following is an omitted code.

```
class ImageCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var contentImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var imageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func prepare(url: String) {
        contentImageView.kf.setImage(url: url) { image in 
            let height = self.contentImageView.bounds.width / image.size.width * image.size.height
            self.heightConstraint.constant = min(300, height)
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

`prepare()` is called with`cellForRowAt` of `tableView`

However, the height of TableViewCell does not change well.

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

P.S.

```
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    ffunc tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.elements.count
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.prepare(url: elements[indexPath.row].url)
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your Tableview datasource and delegate method here?

Comment: if us want dynamic cell hight, then prerequired image's `aspect ratio` or `width`

Comment: @HPM Hi, I added a datasource methods !

Comment: @SPatel The width of imageview is fixed with autolayout.

Comment: why don't you use `heightForRowAt` for dynamic height ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose for that he need width or ratio of image, right?

Comment: @touyu, I asked you add Tableview delegate not UICollectionview!. have set tableview.estimatedrowheight = #YOUR_ESTIMATED_HEIGHT# and tableview.rowheight = .automatic

Comment: @KarthikeyanBose Actually, there is TextCell besides ImageCell. TextCell automatically determines the height of Cell according to the height of Label. So, I do not want to use `heightForRowAt`

Comment: @HPM I'm sorry, I made a mistake. It was `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: @HPM Was not `Self-Sizing` going to default from iOS 11?

Comment: simple answer it's not possible without `heightForRowAt`

Comment: @SPatel Agreed!

Answer (score 1):

Put leading, top, bottom and right constraint on UIImageView in the cell.

Return the height of image in heightForRow method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return image.size.height
}
```

Comment: what if image is not available at that time!!

Comment: In that case, you should use default temp height like 100. And reload table cell when the image gets downloaded.